# Immutability in react redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If I write my reducer in the following way, then the "render" method is getting called and its a expected behavior. No problem here  :

```
const initState = {
    entries: ["test1"]
};

export const EntryReducer = (state = initState, action) => {


    switch (action.type) {


        case ADD_ENTRY:

            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                entries: state.entries.concat("test2")
            });


            break;

        case DELETE_ENTRY:

            break;
    }


    return state;
}
```

But, if I write the reducer in the following way, then the "render" method is not getting called though state is being updated :

```
export const EntryReducer = (state = initState, action) => {

    let newState = Object.assign({}, state);

    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_ENTRY:

            newState.entries.push("test2");

            break;

        case DELETE_ENTRY:

            break;
    }
    return newState;
}
```

I could not understand why render is not getting called. As far as I understand, "newState" is a immutable object and does not hold any reference to the "state" object.

Please help me understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the way you update the state. Consider it correct, though I would not recommend to avoid common best practices.
In your case **render** is not called because component props is not changed...

I believe that you may have something like this:

```
<Component entries={this.props.entries}/>
```

and

```
mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  entries: state.entries
})
```

If it is so, then `state.entries` is the prop that controls whether your component will be re-rendered or not. If it has the same value during the state change on `ADD_ENTRY` action - the component will not be re-rendered.
So. Get back to roots. Remember that in JavaScript `state.entries` is a **POINTER**, that points to array in memory.
While you calling `entries.push` the array in memory will be extended with another element - thats for sure. BUT the **POINTER value** that we have in `state.entries` will remain the same. It will be not changed. Thats how `Array.push` works.

As the result `<Component entries={this.props.entries}/>` will not be re-rendered.
By changing `newState.entries.push("test2");` 
to

```
newState.entries = newState.entries.concat("test2");
```

you actually changing `entries` pointer, component sees that property `props.entries` has changed and now the whole thing re-renders...

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful explanation. I have understood it now.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Object.assign` is shallow, it will not create a new Array, the old one will be mutated by `.push()`:

```
state.entries === newState.entries // ["test1", "test2"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

> "newState" is a immutable object

If you don't do that on your own, it's ordinary object/array/etc so it is not immutable.

> why render is not getting called

React-redux tries its best and actually wraps your component into [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). It does that to make all your `connect()`-ed components *will not* re-render on *any* action called but only once store has been updated in *relevant* places.

To realize if relevant data has been changed or not, `PureComponent` compares shallowly like `oldDataProp !== newDataProp`. Once you mutate objects/arrays that check will fail so component will not re-render.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use other alternatives because `Object.assign()` copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

You should use a Deep clone.

```
let newState= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.